# Error: Request failed with status code 404 in react native on a working API call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, error-handling

I'm facing an issue from axios which is returning a 404 error on api call. This
API end point is already using many times in my application but in a particular scenario this API is returning 404 error status in catch block. Here is the scenario..

I have created an invite link to my application and when a user click on the invite link they will redirect to the Application and on startup I'm displaying a popup component with buttons. when the user click the button to join a particular event on the Application axios patch request is returning 404 error status on catch block. But in other cases this API is working fine. Anybody knows how this is happening..

here is the code sample

```
{gameId != "" &&
      <GameInvitationPopup
        id={gameId}
        setGameId={setGameId}
      />
    }
```

When we click on the GameInvitation pupup,

```
 <View style={{ alignItems: 'center', marginVertical: 20 }}>
                                <Text style={styles.h3Black}>Will you join the game?</Text>
                                <View style={[styles.rowFlex, { marginTop: 10 }]}>
                                    <TouchableOpacity
                                        onPress={() => updateGameData(1)}
                                        activeOpacity={0.6}
                                        style={styles.yesView}>
                                        <Text style={styles.h3Medium}>Yes</Text>
                                    </TouchableOpacity>
                                    <TouchableOpacity
                                        onPress={() => updateGameData(2)}
                                        activeOpacity={0.6}
                                        style={styles.noView}>
                                        <Text style={styles.h3Medium}>No</Text>
                                    </TouchableOpacity>
                                    <TouchableOpacity
                                        onPress={() => updateGameData(3)}
                                        activeOpacity={0.6}
                                        style={styles.maybeView}>
                                        <Text style={styles.h3Medium}>Maybe</Text>
                                    </TouchableOpacity>
                                </View>
                            </View>
```

When we click on the updateGameData function,

```
const updateGameData = (stat) => {

    setLoading(true)
   gameStatusUpdateApiNw(id, stat) 
        .then((out) => {
            setGameId("")
            setLoading(false)
            setShowAlert(true)
        })
        .catch(() => {
            
            setLoading(false)
        })
}
```

This is the API request code, this API is a working API and and the body provide is correct, but still I'm getting 404 error status,

```
  const gameStatusUpdateApiNw = async (id, status) => {
  const state = store.default.getState();
  const token = state.authReducer.authToken;
  const url = `${BASE_URL}/api/games/status/${id}`;
  console.log('status url is ', url);
  try {
    const {data} = await patchRequest(
      url,
      {status: status},
      {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
        },
      },
    );
    console.log('data game ', data);
    return data;
  } catch (e) {
    throw e;
  }
};
```

Anybody knows how this error occur in a working API when we provide correct body into it. Please help

Comment: I think this could be a problem with the backend(API) part. do you have the code for the backend?

Comment: Yes, you were right. the problem was with backend part. I have to provide some more details to the backend to validate the API . Anyway thanks

Comment: @junaif What did you do in the backend, what was the missing part? I have the similar error with a working api call, could you share your experience, thanks.

Comment: @KhanKhan The missing part was nothing but the backend developer told me to add the body for the updation of the patch request. But I'm supposed to provide more details in the patch request. That was the missing part for me in this issue.